# RabbitMQ Management Console on Cloud9

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud9-ide

Does anyone know how to get to the rabbitmq web management console on cloud9?

I see it is running, but bound to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to RabbitMQ, but after a bit of googling and experimentation, I was able to run the management console.

The problem is that only port 8080 is forwarded from your Cloud9 workspace, and RabbitMQ's default port is explained [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#configuration):

> The web UI is located at: http://server-name:15672/

To fix, we need to modify the configuration to start the web UI at port 8080. Here are the steps I followed to get that working:

- Install RabbitMQ (Steps outlined here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html)
- Enable the management console: `sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`
- There wasn't a rabbitmq.config file for me in `$RABBITMQ_HOME/etc/rabbitmq/`, so I copied the example from `/usr/share/doc/rabbitmq-server/` (after unzipping it).
- Edited `$RABBITMQ_HOME/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` and found the `rabbitmq_management` key. There's already an existing setup that's commented out. I replaced it with:

  `{listener, [{port,     8080},
               {ip,       "0.0.0.0"},
               {ssl,     false}]}`

Then I restarted the RabbitMQ server and visiting my url, i.e.: `https://<workspacename>-<username>.c9.io` showed me the RabbitMQ management login screen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @Mutahhir. Now to see if the TCP setting works for celery as it's broker.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark it as 'answered' if it actually helped. It gives the people who visit in the future confidence that the advice can be relied upon.

Comment: I did, no worries. ;)